# Why is the element of this array not changing. I am trying to create a Flag Array to check whether element 'x' is present or not? Is it new C++concept

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to create a flag array to see whether an element is present or not.

Input:

```
2 1 4
+ 1
+ 2
- 1
- 2
```

Desired Output:

```
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

// Create a function 
// Function is passed with values n=2, m=1, q=4,
// and an array of string 
// where str[0] = "+ 1", str[1] = "+ 2", str[2] = "- 1", str[3] = "- 2"
void func(int n, int m, int q, string s[])
{
    // Create an array 
    int *array;
    array = new int[n + 1];
    
    // OUTPUT:: Print array element values to check elements
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;


    // Iterate over the string s[array]
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        // Check if str[i] starts with '+'
        if (s[i][0] == '+')
        {
            
            // Set the index
            int index = s[i][2];
            
            // Set the array element to 1 to identify
            array[index] = 1;
            
            /*
            Check if "index is correct" and "array[index] is set to 1" ----- YES YES YES
            
            cout << "index is: " << s[i][2] << ". "
                 << "ptr[s[i][2]] is: " << ptr[index] << endl;
            */
            
            // OUTPUT:: Iterate over the array to see its elements
            for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
            {
                cout << array[j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, m, q;
    cin >> n >> m >> q;
    cin.ignore();
    string str[q];

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, str[i]);
    }

    func(n, m, q, str);

    return 0;
}
```

Please check it. I have made it simple by writing comments in the above code.

I am new to C++ and do not understand why the array elements are not changing to 1.

Whether it is a new C++ concept, or my code has mistakes. As far as I know, it should work.  But it is not working.

Comment: You may want to use a different data structure, such as `bitset`, `set` or `std::map`.

Comment: When you print the first time: `cout << array[i] << " ";`  the array has not been initialized.

Comment: If you **must** use an array, consider using `std::vector`, as it manages memory for you (such as expanding).

Comment: `int index = s[i][2];` is an ASCII character. So its something like '0' or '1'. To turn this into a number you'll need something like `int index = s[i][2]-'0';`

Comment: There is no guarantee that the `new` operator will always set values in an array to zero.  I recommend initializing the array values after you allocate the array.